# jquery validation making submit button div going under other input divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this problem with jQuery validation. When submit button is pressed, the div goes under the other input field divs. It needs to push down.

Tried to add this

```
.form-horizontal > .col-xs-7{
    height:693px;
}
```

This kinda works. But makes a huge space when submit button has not been pressed yet.

[Here is](http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/plush_form.do) a link where I am working on

Comment: So you want the button to go straight down, instead of to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, the solution is pretty simple. Put a `div` around the top area(the bottom should be above the register button), and then you may have to put the following line in right above the button and put `style="float:left;"` in the other div, but I doubt it:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Then put a div around the area where the register button is, and `text-align:center;`

Although that is pretty easy to do, I would fix the cause, not the problem. Add area for the error messages, so that when they appear, they don't shift the whole page around.

Comment: Thanks found the issue. I had a fixed height for the fieldset. I removed that and added padding bottom rather. That fixed the cause and hence the problem solved. Your solution helps too. Thanks